# how to add an Open Graph og:description a href link along with php echo statement

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I´m creating OpenGraph protocol head descriptions and wanted to fancy up the outputted code to eventually display the (("the description" *along with* [View Collection...](http://www.example.com))) as an additional trailing linkable word.

**The working simple code is this:**

```
 <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $this->getDescription() ?>"/>
```

I´ve unsuccessfully used this:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $this->getDescription() ?> <a href="http://www.example.com">view collection...</a>"/>
```

Since this meta property tag is within the head, it creates a problem with an a href statement. Is there a proper way for this to be done? Additionally, I think the syntax is wrong.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can't put hyperlinks inside a meta tag, I'm afraid. Neither the HTML standard nor Facebook's OpenGraph standard supports the effect you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `<meta property="og:url" content="http://yourlink.com">` to send a link for your *Collection*. It want display inside your description, but if you properly present you USP and direct viewers to use it you will get the same result. @user816749